# select запрос на pymysql не выдает русские символы

Tags: python, sql, select, pymysql

Допустим есть такой запрос:

```
select bouquet_id as 'id букета' from bouquets
```

При выполнении его и выводе на html странице получается подобное:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите варианты проблем или ее решения

Comment: *Допустим есть такой запрос* .. , который синтаксически неверный. Имена объектов квотируются не одинарной кавычкой, а обратной. Ну и кодировка консоли/клиента явно не соответствует кодировке соединения... значения в UTF8, а отображение в CP1251.

Comment: На счет кавычки все верно, я же хочу заголовок заменить текстом

Comment: `на html странице`, вероятно, указана кодировка cp1251. её либо вообще не надо указывать, либо указать ту, в которой у вас и есть текст — юникод.

Comment: Да, помогло декодировать из cp1251 в utf-8